# Why should I use connect_timeout=5 in pg_connect() function?

Tags: php, postgresql

I recently got a comment that I should "use connect_timeout in my script". I went searching for what was actually meant by this and I found this information on [php.net](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.pg-connect.php) in the user comments:

```
One thing is to remember, whenever trying to use pg_connect, add the timeout 
parameter with it

<?php 
$d=pg_connect('host=example.com user=pgsql dbname=postgres connect_timeout=5'); 
?>
```

So, again, same information "you should use it", but no explanation to as why? So, I was hoping someone can clarify this for me?

Also, is there some "default" `connect_timeout` that should be set, like as the user comment suggests `5`? Is for some reason `pg_connect` a bad choice, and I should add this `connect_timeout` in every `pg_connect` call, or?

I searched in the [pgsql documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/libpq-connect.html) and it's said only that:

```
connect_timeout
Maximum wait for connection, in seconds (write as a decimal integer string). Zero
or not specified means wait indefinitely. It is not recommended to use a timeout
of less than 2 seconds.
```

But I don't see a use case scenario for this, and frankly I've never used it before, so, anyways, some insights to this would be grateful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a website, there are at least two reasons to set a connection timeout, in case the connection to the database hangs:

- degrade gracefully with an appropriate error message and logging instead of letting the user wait until bored.
- don't let the webserver accumulate processes and risk reaching its limits (such as `maxclients` for apache) to the point it won't serve any request at all. Generally we want any web request to finish as soon as possible.